# is there any way to run bottle application in daemon mode

Tags: python, bottle

I have a web application built on bottle(python) frame work and I want to run it in daemon mode.Is there any way to run it in daemon mode

Thanks

Comment: You can use [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) to daemonize and control bottle. See [this article](http://jamie.curle.io/blog/bottle-and-supervisord/) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Install [BottleDaemon 0.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BottleDaemon/0.1.0) on your OS and than change your router file like so:

```
    from bottledaemon import daemon_run
    from bottle import route

    @route("/hello")
    def hello():
      return "Hello World"

    # The following lines will call the BottleDaemon script and launch a daemon in the background.
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      daemon_run()
```