# Running a daemonized bottle application with nginx

Tags: python, nginx, daemon, bottle

I have a bottle application (specifically, [homu](https://github.com/barosl/homu)) which I want to deploy on a server.

The traditional way to run this application is to just run the program (eg `python whatever.py`), without any server integration. The application is stateful and updates its state by listening to the github webhooks api. It also has a configuration panel that bottle delivers.

Whilst it is able to recover from a crash, this requires a lot of GitHub API requests (which get throttled), so it's preferable to have it running continuously.

Now, I know [how to daemonize a bottle application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135159/is-there-any-way-to-run-bottle-application-in-daemon-mode), but this requires running it as a separate program running on a separate port from nginx. I'd like to have nginx delegate certain paths to the running bottle application.

How do I do this?

(Alternatively, a way for me to set it up so that nginx is responsible for keeping it running is nice too)

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to reverse-proxy it.

```
location /foo/bar {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:someport/;
}
```

and then run the bottle application on `someport`